# Oracle SQL - Summarize data based on values in one column

Tags: sql, oracle, summarize

Please review the following sample data

| App No | Dept | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | IT | Pending |
| 124 | Sales | Closed |
| 456 | Sales | Declined |
| 821 | IT | Pending |
| 221 | IT | Closed |
| 876 | Sales | Pending |
| 665 | Sales | Closed |

Could you please suggest an oracle sql query that can provide the following output

| Dept | Closed | Pendng | Declined |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IT | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| Sales | 2 | 1 | 1 |

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH CTE(App_No,Dept,Status) AS
(
  SELECT 123,'IT','Pending' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 124,   'Sales' ,   'Closed' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 456,   'Sales' ,   'Declined' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 821,   'IT' ,  'Pending' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 221,   'IT' ,  'Closed' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 876,   'Sales' ,   'Pending' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 665,   'Sales' ,   'Closed' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT C.DEPT,
  SUM(CASE WHEN C.STATUS='Closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CLOSED,
  SUM(CASE WHEN C.STATUS='Declined' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)DECLINED,
  SUM(CASE WHEN C.STATUS='Pending' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)PENDING
  FROM CTE C
 GROUP BY C.DEPT
 ORDER BY C.DEPT
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1d61ba161051cdff7ca7af622961ee2b

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, this was just a sample. The actually data set has thousands of records. So I dont think I can use union all with that.

Comment: That's just sample data, Farhan, you don't type that. Query you'd use begins with `SELECT C.DEPT ...`